# How we can show only one shipping method at time in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, shipping-methods

We have two shipping methods

**1.Yamato**

**2.Gdex**

We want to show only one shipping method at time based on our custom order sequencing rule. at the same time want to change price(**dynamically**) of shipping methods based order sequencing rule.
for more clarity. you can see image.

[image]

Comment: please check your admin settings store/configuration/sales/shipping-settings turn on/off methods and change other settings as per your needs thanks

Comment: Thanks but at file level where and which file is need to override ? Could you please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

The class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` has the function `collectShippingRates`, this is responsible for shipping methods. 
You can try with this class by overriding.

Comment: how can change rate of shipping method and make available only one shipping method at time? methods and their price will change based on my condition so how i can do that?

Comment: when you check `requestShippingRates()` function in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` class, you can see the line called `$shippingRates = $result->getAllRates();` . This contains the complete array of the shipping rates. You can use that foreach to control each rate